# Python equivalent of Javascript Object.values() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Javascript I can use the `Object.values()` method to iterate over the *values* of an object.

For example (Javascript):

```
const myObj = {
  'a': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
  'b': [1, 2, 3],
  'c': [true, false, null], // For Python [True, False, None]
}
const values = Object.values(myObj)
```

Where `values` contains:

```
[
    ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [true, false, null], // for Python [True, False, None]
]
```

What is the simplest, build in way to get only the values of the dictionary in Python? (which mean a list of lists in this example)

Comment: Your constants are incorrectly specified in python, you need `[True, False, None]`

Answer (score 0):

In Python we can use the `.values()` method to iterate over and get the *values* of a dictionary.

For example:

```
mydict = {
  'a': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
  'b': [1, 2, 3],
  'c': [True, False, None],
}
values = mydict.values()
```

Where `values` contains:

```
[
    ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [True, False, None],
]
```

Comment: Note that `values` here is not strictly a list (in python 3), it is a dict view